# Invalid configuration of route '': redirectTo and children cannot be used together

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to navigate from a component to another but i got this problem :Invalid configuration of route '': redirectTo and children cannot be used together.
How can i fix it please?

route file :

```
    {
    path: '',
     redirectTo: 'offre-management', pathMatch: 'full',

children: [
  { path: 'offre-mngmnt-sites-list-all',
    component: OffreMngmntSitesListAllComponent }
]
  }
```

html file when i am invoking method to navigate to the OffreMngmntSitesListAllComponent component:

```
<span role="button" (click)="showAll()">
  show all
</span>
```

and the ts file of when i have the method that will call the OffreMngmntSitesListAllComponent component:

```
 showAll(){
this.router.navigate(["offre-mngmnt-sites-list-all"])
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `OffreMngmntSitesListAllComponent` is really your child component then your routes should be like this:

```
const routes = {
 path: 'offre-management',
 component: ${your office management component},
 children: [
   {
    path: 'offre-mngmnt-sites-list-all',
    component: OffreMngmntSitesListAllComponent
   },
   {
    path: '', redirectTo: 'offre-management', pathMatch: 'full',
   }
  ]
 };
```

And your navigation would be like:

```
this.router.navigate(["offre-management/offre-mngmnt-sites-list-all"])
```